# Rotating whole object for other shape key

Tags: animation, shape-keys, lattice

I have made this pretty little eye lid here:
[image]

and I added a lattice to deform it, so it doesn't go beyond the border. (It's actually a half sphere)
Now I want to have a second shape key, where the eye lids are closed (the full sphere is rotated to the front) and it is not an issue, if I actually rotate the sphere. But when I rotate the vertices the lattice deformation applies to them and everything gets messed up.
So my question is: Is there a way to

- a) make a shape key with rotation of whole object
- b) make the lattice only apply to one shape key
- c) some other way to make sure, that the lid does not overlay the (imaginary) hollow eyeball.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very short:

a) Shapekeys only translates vertices from point A to point B, no rotation involved. Why not just rotate the sphere object itself, or use a bone to do that?

b) you can add a driver to control the lattice modifier's strength with a shapekey's.
Set the shapekey's value to 1, Right click the value → copy as driver. Right click modifier's strength → paste as new driver:

[image: demo drivers]

To push it even further, if you want the modifier to be disabled ONLY when the shapekey is fully disactivated with no transition:

Right click the driven modifier strenght → Open driver editor.
Select all the graph with <kbd>A</kbd>, open the interpolation menu with <kbd>T</kbd> and choose constant.
Still with all the graph selected, press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>. It should look like this:

[image: driver edit]

c) Not sure what you're looking for exactly.